# How to access my file system from a dockered pgadmin4

Tags: docker, pgadmin-4

I tried to install pgadmin4 on my system in several ways, but each time I was defeated by the intricacies of the install. Luckily I discovered a Dockerfile (dpage/pgadmin4) and that worked out of the box. In my docker-compose.yml I added a volume statement

```
volumes:
    - /var/lib/pgadmin4:/var/lib/pgadmin
```

In order to preserve the pgadmin data over successive runs. pgadmin4 is accessible from 0.0.0.0:5050 and all works fine.

However, I cannot access the files from my local file system with the query tool, this is all hidden in the docker file system. Fortunately that is in the `/var/lib/pgadmin4` system on my local machine. In that directory there is a directory `storage` and that contains the id I use to login as the name of a directory: the ID `x@y.z` becomes directory `x_y.z` and that contains the files and folders I had created from my browser as a test. I tried to change this in the pgadmin4 options to `/home/user/development` but that path is not recognized because it is not in `x_y.z`.

Question: how can I change pgadmin4's path from `/var/lib/pgadmin4/storage/x_y.z` into `/home/user/development`?

**Update**

I tried to link a part of my home directory into `/var/lib/pgadmin4/storage/x_y.z` as a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/Documents
```

After that command there exists a linked directory `/var/lib/pgadmin4/storage/x_y.z/Documents` with uid:gid being root:root and 777 permission. When I next start the query toolbox and click at `open` the open box appears and I get 4 identical error messages:

```
Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /var/lib/pgadmin4/storage/x_y.z/Documents
```

I have changed the owner:group to the relevant ones I could think of:

```
1000:1000 (me as user)
root:root
5050:5050 (pgadmin uid and gid)
```

In all three cases I got this error. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You override paths in config_local.py (you can create it if not exists already).

> STORAGE_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'storage')

to

> STORAGE_DIR = '/home/user/Documents'

Restart pgAdmin4.

Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.22/config_py.html

Comment: Thanks! Where exactly should I place that file? I could not gather this from the documentation.

Comment: Oh sorry in docker, you need to set the environment variables refer https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html#environment-variables here check the `PGADMIN_CONFIG_` section